# Does buying a Police Car reduce the chances of getting into a police pursuit?

Tags: midnight-club-los-angeles

In Midnight Club: Los Angeles for the PS3, I bought a police car. But I was wondering if buying one would reduce the risk of a police pursuit?

Answer (score 1):

Buying a Police Car will negate any chances of getting a police pursuit unless you drive through a public area or if the story line automatically sends the Police. Example, when racing with Brooke against Chung Hee and his buddy. The game is set to send Police after you when you are close to finishing the race.